# VK API ничего на выходит

Tags: php, json, vkontakte-api

Помогите, выводит пустое окно при выполнение запроса

```
<?php

    $url = "http://vk.com";
    $request_params = array(
    'url' => $url,
    'v' => '5.63'
    );
    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/utils.getShortLink?'. $get_params));
    echo($result -> response[0] -> short_url);
    ?>
```

Comment: так а с чего ты взял, что тебе прям вот 10000% приходит ответ с данными, в которых есть `short_url`, а не сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было замечено, на самом деле [utils.getShortLink](https://vk.com/dev/utils.getShortLink) возвращает ошибку №15 (ошибка доступа), потому что этот метод обязательно нужно вызывать с ключём доступа, передавая его в параметре **access_token**.

Если у вас приложение работает от имени какого-либо пользователя ВК, я думаю, было бы целесообразно, использовать уже полученный токен. Если же хочется сократить ссылку без привязки к текущему пользователю, передавайте сервисный ключ доступа, который можно найти в настройках приложения.

---

И да, поскольку ответ возвращается только один, уберите индексатор у поля **response**. Там не массив.

Comment: `<?php
$access_token = 'token';
$url = 'https://vk.coms'
   $request_params = array(
   'user_id' => $access_token,
   'url' => $url,
   'v' => '5.63'
);
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/utils.getShortLink?'. $get_params));
echo($result -> response -> short_url);
?> ` Ошибка 500

Comment: @Perumn не `'user_id' => $access_token,`, а `'access_token' => $access_token,` ......... надеюсь вы понимаете в чем разница? ...... ошибки все расписаны в `response`........ почему бы вам иногда в них не смотреть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ой, мой косяк. Как просмотреть ошибки?

Comment: @Perumn var_dump или print_r .......распечатываешь `$result->response` и смотришь что тебе именно приходит